# Pandas - Apply transformation on every subset (selected over n columns)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm currently working with the following dataframe, there is around 300k lines, and 4k unique id_user.

I want to "merge" lines with the same {id_user,date,id_item} into one line containing the mean of {qty,price}.

[image: DataFrame]

This is the simplest idea that I've implemented so far, but I'm sure there is a better way to do this properly.

The idea here is just to iterate over every subset of the dataframe with the same {id_user,date,id_item} then keep the first line, and replace it's {qty, price} by the mean of the subset. After delete the other lines by changing their id_user to "DEL" and blanking all other attributes. (I must keep those entries in the DF)

```
def mergeIdentical():
dates = df["date"].unique()
users=df["id_user"].unique()
for d in dates:
    for u in users:
        mask=(df["date"]==d) & (df["id_user"]==u)
        ids = df[mask]["id_item"].unique()
        for i in ids:
            mask=(df["date"]==d) & (df["id_user"]==u) & (df["id_item"]==i)
            df.loc[df[mask].index[0],"qty"]=df[mask]["qty"].mean()
            df.loc[df[mask].index[0],"price"]=df[mask]["price"].mean()       
            if(len(df[mask].index)>1):
                df.loc[df[mask].index[1:],"id_user"]="DEL"
                df.loc[df[mask].index[1:],["date","hours","id_item","price","qty","month","year"]]=''
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['id_user', 'date', 'id_item'], as_index=False).mean()[['qty', 'price']]
```

Comment: Do you know how I could merge this result in the initial dataframe ?

Comment: If by "merge" you mean "replace", do `df = df.groupby...` instead of `grouped_df = df.groupby...`. And if you want to add those new lines at the end of the existing one, do `df = df.append(grouped_df)`

Comment: There are multiple problems with this, firstly : indexes in the newly created grouped_df do not correspond to those in the initial df, so a simple df["price"]=df.group.by... won't work, second : i still need to find a way to "delete" all the (n-1) lines in each partition while keeping the first line.

Comment: @FeatherAndInk How do you expect that the index in the "merged lines" you create will ever correspond to the original's? By definition you have now much less rows. And my solution gave you a single row for each group. If you want to stay with just one row, why did you ask how to add it to the original df?